# Does 纬哲/纬喆 mean 'threads of wisdom', 'weaving widsom' or something similar?

Tags: meaning, characters

纬 seems to mean latitude or weft/woof but I am not sure if it would work in this way with the second meaning

As an additional question, would 炜喆 mean brilliant wisdom? Is the character 炜 a character that most people would know?

Would either of these make sense as a fictional character's first name? (An adult male in the 21st century)

Comment: 炜喆 sounds cool but kinds of hard to get the meaning at the first glance, since both of them are 生僻字 (rare characters) compared to 纬哲

Comment: @sichengmao Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, 纬 means both "woof" and "parallels of latitude".
2. In itself, 炜 (brilliant red; glowing) isn't a frequently used word, but its equal, "辉” (bright; glorious), is. Note that 喆 (wise; sagacious) is also a rarely used word, but its equal, “哲” (philosophy) is. Yes, 炜喆 can be interpreted as "brilliant wisdom".
3. It will depend on the character you want to depict.

Comment: Thanks. I wish you could upvote you but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Thank you. Wish your story going well.